# How to ensure Google Maps works after migrating to Firebase?

Tags: android, json, google-maps, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I recently imported a GCM project into Firebase.
I have downloaded the JSON file and the app is working, however when I launch the map it fails on authorization with the error **"Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:"**

I know this has to do with the google maps service not being enabled for the project but that is not the case.
When I revert the project to **not** use Firebase and just use the **google_maps_api.xlm** file then it works again.

I have looked into the generated Firebase JSON file and noticed that there is an **app_id** and an **api_key**.
In the developers console I can see the **api key** in the api credentials section for maps so to my understanding this **app_id** should have access to maps.
When it fails it asks to ensure that the Android Key exists, here it mentions the **app_id** and not the **api_key**.

Does anyone know what I am missing? I am pretty stumped with this one. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've managed a workaround to this by adding a new value in the google_maps_api.xml file and using that instead of the previous value but it still doesn't answer why the google-services.json file won't work. Has anybody else experienced this?